# Create a dictionary (d3) consisting of items unique to two other dictionaries (d1, d2)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm out of ideas here.
I've got:

```
d1 = {1:30, 2:20, 3:30, 5:80}
d2 = {1:40, 2:50, 3:60, 4:70, 6:90}
```

I'd like to create:

```
d3 = {4:70, 5:80, 6:90}
```

I realize how trivial this is, hence my frustration. If you've got any ideas, please share.

Comment: @mrkaran: no you describe is the union. This is a difference dictionary.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Oh, I just realized it!

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: no it depends on whether the question looks like the one of a lazy student wanting his homework done, or someone with a real (and specific) problem. Some questions are like "**Task 1**:"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersection and Difference of two dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805266/intersection-and-difference-of-two-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symmetric difference `^` finds the unique keys.  Then it's an easy dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: d1.get(k, d2.get(k)) for k in (set(d1) ^ set(d2))}
{4: 70, 5: 80, 6: 90}
```

The method above is cross-compat code.  It looks a bit nicer if you don't need to deal with Python 2:

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> d12 = ChainMap(d1, d2)
>>> {k: d12[k] for k in d1.keys() ^ d2.keys()}
{4: 70, 5: 80, 6: 90}
```

Note: The keys "view" objects here are also available in Python 2 under the method `d.viewkeys()`.

Comment: Could also just use `d1.keys() ^ d2.keys()` instead of constructing two new sets with `set(d1) ^ set(d2)`.

Comment: @ajcr, `dict.keys` returns a list in Python 2.x; `list ^ list` is not supported.

Comment: @wim Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to achieve

Comment: @falsetru: that's true, I should have said my comment was 3.x specific.

Comment: Strangely, `set ^ list` is not supported, but `dict_keys ^ list` is OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
def dictJoin(d1, d2):
    return {k: d1[k] if k in d1 else d2[k] for k in set(d1) ^ set(d2)}

d1 = {1:30, 2:20, 3:30, 5:80}
d2 = {1:40, 2:50, 3:60, 4:70, 6:90}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d3 = dictJoin(d1, d2)
    print d3
```

Comment: You can use dictionary comprehension for this.

Comment: `dictJoin` is not a great name, but otherwise the idea is good.